# How do I set keyboard shortcuts for my menubar in a Java application?

Tags: java, keyboard-shortcuts, awt, menubar

I'm developing a simple drawing application in Java.  I'm restricted to using an AWT MenuBar (Not JMenuBar), and I need to set a few keyboard shortcuts and I can't find how to do so.  I need shortcuts for two MenuItems and for three CheckBoxMenuItems.

It would go something like this:

```
newItem = Ctrl+N
quitItem = Ctrl+Q
rectangleItem = Ctrl+R
ovalItem = Ctrl+O
lineItem = Ctrl+L
```

Comment: Have you seen [this documentation?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/awt/1.3/designspec/mouseless.html) I'm not familiar with AWT, but it seems relevent...

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for posting, I checked it out, and I'm trying to implement it, but i can't figure out what I need to #import to make it work.  it says it's part of Component, and i have awt.* imported, but it doesn't seem to be working.  Also, it says i need to override isFocusTraversable on Canvas, and I'm not sure how to do that.

EDIT: Wow! That worked beautifully for MenuItems, but it doesn't work for CheckBoxMenuItems

Comment: That's just an example for if you were implementing your own version of `Canvas` - don't worry about that. All you should have to do is provide the second argument to the constructor for each `MenuItem` - as is shown in the second half of that documentation.

Comment: Adding the second arguments worked fantastically for each `MenuItem` but it doesn't work for CheckBoxMenuItems

Comment: Ok, I'm afraid I'm all out of input here - I don't actually have the ability to compile code on this machine. You might consider asking another question specifically about `CheckBoxMenuItem`s though - the more specific the question the better the answers you get.

Comment: Absolutely will do.  If you'd like to put your first comment as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the suggestion in the comments seems to have fixed at least part of your problem, I'm gonna put it here as an answer for users in the future.

Read the second half of [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/awt/1.3/designspec/mouseless.html) and change your `MenuItem` constructors to take in a `MenuShortcut` as their second argument, like this (taken from the linked docs):

```
menu.add(new MenuItem("Save...", new MenuShortcut('s'));
```

Answer (score 0):

it would be easyer if:

put a layered pane? a glass in front, which will accept keyboard event in the whole area.

- not sure what components is for awt, but for sure you have a very good reason to use it, not just look and feel?

There you set the shortcuts.